# milliseconds from solaris command line

Tags: solaris

This gnu date command lets me get milliseconds this way:

```
date +%M:%S.%N;
```

but this command doesn't work on solaris... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "shell script" should display milliseconds:

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ ! -x /var/tmp/time_ms ]
then
    cat > /tmp/time_ms.c << %
    #include <sys/time.h>
    main()
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv,(void*)0);
        printf("%d.%d\n",tv.tv_sec,tv.tv_usec/1000);
    }
%
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw gcc /tmp/time_ms.c -o /var/tmp/time_ms
fi
/var/tmp/time_ms
```

Of course, you can relocate time_ms in your PATH and call it directly after the first run. That will provide a faster solution than gnu date or any perl/whatever script.

Comment: hey hey - this looks like a nice idea, jiliagre.  However, I'm getting this error:
./time_ms.sh[2]: syntax error at line 4 : `<<' unmatched
any ideas?

Comment: I fixed my script for it to work with legacy ksh and others shells. It was working fine with ksh93 so I didn't notice.

Comment: yep - very cool.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that Solaris doesn't use GNU date or doesn't have the latest version. The [Solaris man page for date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/date-1.html#scrolltoc) doesn't mention the `%N` formatting option. The GNU coreutils docs for [time conversion specifiers](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html#Time-conversion-specifiers) for `date` specifically say that `%N` is a GNU extension (oh -- it's nanoseconds, not milliseconds).

If you need the milliseconds, your best bet is to download the latest [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) and install it under `/usr/local` (or `/opt/local` if you prefer). To get the proper version of `date`, you either  configure your `PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` or use a full path to `/usr/local/bin/date` in your script.

Comment: I'm not the sysadmin.  Is there no other solaris command to do it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can install `coreutils` under your home directory. You can also try Aaron Digulla's perl suggestion.

Comment: What do you get if you type this in bash: `type -a date`?

Comment: I'm trying to put coreutils in my home directory now...


        $ type -a date
        date is /usr/bin/date
        date is /bin/date

Comment: I tried this as well. I did `./configure --prefix=/home/myuser`. Coreutils files were installed in `bin`, `lib` and `share` subdirectories under my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're measuring the time taken by a part of the script, you can put this part of the script in a function and call `time myfunction`. You can also call the `times` builtin before and after the section you want to time, but doing the arithmetic yourself is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

TSP_MSEC=`perl -MTime::HiRes -e 'print int(1000 * Time::HiRes::gettimeofday),"\n"'`
MSEC=`echo $TSP_MSEC | cut -c11-13`

TSP=`date +%d.%m.20%y" "%H:%M:%S.$MSEC`
echo $TSP
```

Result: 15.07.2014 16:10:01.260

Answer (score 0):

Perl is almost everywhere. Use:

```
perl -e 'print time()*1000;print "\n";'
```

If you really need millisecond accuracy, try the [`Time:HiRes` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html).

[EDIT] Alternatively, compile a small C program which calls `gettimeofday()` and prints the result.

Comment: I'm measuring milliseconds inside of a bash script.  I'm guessing that tarting the perl interpreter would take enough time to throw off my calculations?

Comment: Then use gettimeofday() directly. Or the `time` command for that matter.